# TypeScript - Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having this error output in my react project

```
TypeScript error
Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[]'.
```

**But I can't find out exactly what's wrong with my code, here's:**

```
           const { children } = props;

  > 19 |   const mapChildren = React.Children.map(children, (tread: ReactElement) => tread);
       |                                          ^
    20 |   const child = mapChildren.filter((tread: ReactElement) => tread.props.id === currentTread)[0];
    21 | 
    22 |     useEffect(() => {
              init(mapChildren);
             }, []);
```

What exactly is wrong with the children element?

Comment: `props.children` (you haven't shown in you've destructured `children` out of props, have you)? Also, why are you doing that in an `useEffect`? Maybe `useMemo` might be more up your alley (although unless it's super intensive work you're doing, you could probably skip that, too).

Comment: @Adam 
I really forgot to put the props children here in the code, but it already existed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Fix

This is sufficient and type-safe:

```js
const mapChildren = React.Children.map(children, (tread) => tread);
```

The type of `tread` is prescribed by `Children.map` and inferred by TypeScript.

### Why?

Nothing is wrong with `children` as such.

But we have to ensure that the type of `children` matches the type of the function passed to `Children.map`:

```js
map<T, C>(
  children: C | C[], 
  fn: (child: C, index: number) => T
): C extends null | undefined 
  ? C 
  : Array<Exclude<T, boolean | null | undefined>>;
```

([Source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/72dd979741e12822de7c01062d2ec4faf7cfaec0/types/react/index.d.ts#L2876-L2877))

This means that the type of the `child` argument of `fn` has to be the same as the type of `children` (regardless of whether `children` is a single object or an array).

#### What happens when we pass `(tread: ReactElement) => tread` as `fn`?

We're saying that `fn` will only accept children that are `ReactElement`s.

However, `children` are `ReactNode`s (unless you explicitly type it differently), so React can't pass them through `fn` because of the type mismatch.

#### What's the type mismatch?

`ReactElement` is just one of several possible types of `ReactNode`:

- `type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined`
- `type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText`

#### So, why that error? (*`undefined` is not assignable to `ReactElement`*)?

The error means *"A child might be of type `undefined` but the function you passed to `map` won't accept that."*

`undefined` is the last type in the definition of `ReactNode` and in union types, that's (apparently) what TypeScript does – only complains about the last incompatible type.